# Travis CI and pytest with multiple python versions

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

I have the following in .travis.yml:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5"
  - "3.5-dev" # 3.5 development branch
  - "3.6-dev" # 3.6 development branch
  - "nightly" # currently points to 3.7-dev
# command to run tests
script: pytest
```

The problem is that in python <= 3.5 it's `py.test` instead of `pytest`.

How do I tell travis to use `py.test` for "3.4" and "3.5"?

Comment: You could write your own Python script that invokes pytest as appropriate for the current version, and use that as the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer to my question.

Changed the `script` section to:

```
script:
    - if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 3.4 || $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 3.5 ]]; then py.test;else pytest; fi
```